# MVC5: Allow user to only view and edit their own information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, user-input, user-defined-functions

I created a scaffold based on one of my tables.  I'm now trying to figure out how to allow the user to only view/edit data that is the same as their userID.

Right now it displays all the data from that table and allows for editing of all users.  I need to be able to limit it to only the user that is currently logged in.

Please let me know if I can give any more details.

**Controller**

```
    public class ClientViewStaffController : Controller
{
    private TpsEntities db = new TpsEntities();

    // GET: ClientViewStaff
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.staffTables.ToList());
    }

    // GET: ClientViewStaff/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        staffTable staffTable = db.staffTables.Find(id);
        if (staffTable == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(staffTable);
    }

    // GET: ClientViewStaff/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: ClientViewStaff/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "staffID,staffFirstName,staffLastName,staffTitle,staffAddress,staffCity,staffState,staffZip,staffExperience,staffEducation,desiredSalary,staffProfession,staffAvailibity,staffPhoto,staffEmail,staffPhoneNum,userID")] staffTable staffTable)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.staffTables.Add(staffTable);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(staffTable);
    }

    // GET: ClientViewStaff/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        staffTable staffTable = db.staffTables.Find(id);
        if (staffTable == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(staffTable);
    }

    // POST: ClientViewStaff/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "staffID,staffFirstName,staffLastName,staffTitle,staffAddress,staffCity,staffState,staffZip,staffExperience,staffEducation,desiredSalary,staffProfession,staffAvailibity,staffPhoto,staffEmail,staffPhoneNum,userID")] staffTable staffTable)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(staffTable).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(staffTable);
    }

    // GET: ClientViewStaff/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        staffTable staffTable = db.staffTables.Find(id);
        if (staffTable == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(staffTable);
    }

    // POST: ClientViewStaff/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        staffTable staffTable = db.staffTables.Find(id);
        db.staffTables.Remove(staffTable);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

**View (Index.cshtml)**

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        First Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Last Name
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.staffState)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.staffExperience)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.staffEducation)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.desiredSalary)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.staffProfession)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.staffAvailibity)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffFirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffLastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffState)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffExperience)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffEducation)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.desiredSalary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffProfession)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.staffAvailibity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.staffID }) |

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**View (Details.cshtml)**

```
<div>
<h4>Staff View</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        First Name
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffFirstName)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Last Name
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffLastName)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Title
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffTitle)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Address
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffAddress)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        City
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffCity)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        State
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffState)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Zip Code
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffZip)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Experience
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffExperience)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Education
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffEducation)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Salary
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.desiredSalary)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Profession
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffProfession)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Availability
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffAvailibity)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Photo
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffPhoto)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Email
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffEmail)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Phone Number
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.staffPhoneNum)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        User ID
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userID)
    </dd>

</dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.staffID }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: Couldyou provide some details of your domain model?

Comment: I've never had to explain this before so please bare with me. I Setup View, View Models, Controllers.  I create the project using the MVC 5 Template from MS and dropped what I didn't need.  I used Individual Authentication as I'm connected to my SQL server (not local). Model.edmx is there...  Let me know what in particular you're asking for, tad bit new to this.

Comment: Are you using asp.net identity framework for authentication? If you are happy to use display / hide option for your edit button, then I can give you easy solution.

Comment: Yea I am using identity framework.  I'm interested to see your solution but wouldn't the user still be able to view the information for others and the display/edit option for edit apply to all records?

Comment: Check my answer, comment it, if you need more details.

Comment: @slider1578 i suppose you use entity framework as your data framework between your code ans sql server. How is the userid stored in the other tables and how does this come back in your ef model?

Comment: @Ric.Net  The userID is stored as Varchar in the other tables and is linked through the dbo.AspNetUsers table.  So when a user initially registers they are asked to supply email, password and choose their user type (staff/client). Depending on which is chose another page is loaded to complete registration.  Once that next page is completed it passes the userID from the first page into the staff or client table along with the rest of the information completed on the second page. The site is deployed to tpstaffing.slider-development.com

Comment: @slider1578 And the other tables are also part of your entity framework model.. I hope...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like this in the `Edit, Details` GET action.

```
var loggedInUser = GetUserId(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
if (id != loggedInUser)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
}
```

You can also abstract this away from the controller and put in an Action Filter. Action filters in ASP.NET MVC are C# attributes that separate specific concerns such as security.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate your Edit action with [Authorize] attribute

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    staffTable staffTable = db.staffTables.Find(id);
    if (staffTable == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(staffTable);
}
```

Then hide your edit action for non-logged in users.

First add `@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` to top of your view and then use below code on view.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.staffID })
}
```

**Edited for comment**

As you know that anything you need to restrict non-authenticated users (non-logged in), you have to use [Authorize] attribute as I mentioned.

You didn't mentioned what you exactly restrict access in your question.

If you want to restrict access all your content to the non authenticate user, then add [Authorize] attribute to your controller as below.

```
[Authorize]
public class ClientViewStaffController : Controller
{

}
```

Then all the actions restricted for logged in users only. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: Is there a way to limit the results to only the persons staffID. Currently then I load it pulls everyone from the DB and give the edit option.  I'd like to limit the result to only the person who is logged in.

There is an index.cshtml that pulls everything

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing something about entity framework in combination with Linq aka Linq-to-entities.

Your can write queries against your ef model using Linq. For details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399367(v=vs.100).aspx).

What your basically doing is writing a query in c# and entity framework will convert this query to a sql select statement and run this against your database.

Using this approach your question becomes real simple. Just write a query which fits your needs. Something like this could work

```
public IEnumerable<> FetchData(string userId)
{
    return (
       from item in this.db.staffTables
       where item.UserId == userId
       select item
       ).ToArray();
}
```

A far better approach would be to hide your entity framework model from your controller and use a repository in between. The repository would typically implement four functions: `GetData()', 'Create()', 'Update()` and `Delete()`. In each method you would check if the user is authorized for the action to perform or return only data that the user is authorized to get.